# how can i prevent the sent of emails in the weekend and using STO in the same time?

Tags: email, journeybuilder, einstein, code, scheduled

So we want to prevent the sent of the emails that we have in journeys in Marketing cloud to come out on the week-end ( Saturday and Sunday) but queue it to come up on Monday and to come from 6h AM to 20H PM in the week days  using  the STO einstein ? Is there an Exclusion script to prevent that ? Thank you

Comment: Exclusion scripts don't provide for queueing, although I guess you could use one to write to a Data Extension for later injection or firing of a Wait Until Event activity. How are contacts injected into your journey? Using Automation Studio, API, Salesforce Data, CloudPage?